# DRBD stuck in Connected/WFBitMapS

Tags: drbd

So I am trying to setup a DRBD replication between 2 nodes.
When I restart my primary node, second one gets primary correclty but once the second one is back online, it stays stuck in the below state.

Primary has the following status:  `0:r0/0  WFBitMapS Primary/Secondary UpToDate/Consistent`
and secondary has the following:  `0:r0/0  Connected Secondary/Primary Negotiating/UpToDate`.

Rebooting the secondary node fixes the issue but everytime there is a failover, my nodes get stuck in the above state again.

Below some information on my cluster:

- debian 10
- drbd 8.9.10
- drbd disk size: 6.7TB.

Does anyone has an idea on what's going on or what does this state mean ? I did not find any useful informations on this on Google...
Thank you

Comment: Seems like part of the bitmap isn't getting through. Any chance you're using jumbo frames? Also, that DRBD version is going to be a utils version, which isn't that important. What version of the kernel module do you have loaded? `cat /proc/drbd`

Comment: @MattKereczman Hi Thanks for the reply. I am not using jumbo frames as far as I know. my drbd version is 8.4.10, I will try to update drbd see if it fixes my issue. Also my disk was in MBR partition table, I switched it to GPT idk if it can be related. It is resyncing atm so I will have to wait see the result.